# Is there a way to stop generating ruby stubs in python projects?

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I have a LARGE project including python and javascript code that keeps trying to generate stubs for ruby core now and then.  The project has no ruby code at all.  But every so often Eclipse/Aptana Studio decides to generate stubs, and it takes over an hour.  Seriously.  I am not even exaggerating.

So of course I have tried many ways to attempt to stop this process.  The result is simply that it has to complete before my project is usable again.  At the end of the process, the eclipse ".project" file will end up having an entry for "rubyaspect" which we always delete, because as soon as anyone else does a "git pull" on a project with ruby aspect, their environment ALSO spends over an hour generating ruby stubs.

I have seen some discussion on a bug in cancelling the process, but it appears that the question is still coming from people that are actually using ruby.  Again, this is a python and javascript project only.

Is there any workaround to stopping this process that won't result in restarting the process as soon as I start eclipse again?

ADDENDUM: The Eclipse version in use is Juno, and the AptanaStudio version is 3.2.0

SECOND ADDENDUM: I have just upgraded to AptanaStudio version is 3.2.1.  The same problem persists, but without any mention of ruby core -- it just says "Rebuilding". When it's done, an hour later, it still has added rubyaspect to the project.

--jeff